# Why is this generating a warning?

Tags: ios, addressbook, core-foundation

```
ABMutableMultiValueRef *address = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonAddressProperty);
for (CFIndex i=0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(address); i++) {
    CFDictionaryRef dict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(address, i);
```

The code works but generates a warning. Any clue?

Warning: FirstViewController.m:46: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're getting a warning because you're assigning an `NSString*` value to a `ABMutableMultiValueRef*` variable.  You should only assign a pointer variable to a pointer of the same type.

Comment: how do I fix it? You see that I'm using it to pull data from the multivalue

Comment: I know that but how do I fix it? any suggestions? Xcode tells me that they aren't the same pointer

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure exactly how to fix it.  ABRecordCopyValue returns a CFTypeRef, which is a generic pointer type.  Mark's answer below is probably the path you need to go - you probably need to cast the rest as some CF* type.  Maybe it's not CFString, but it's probably something else that starts with CF.

Answer (score 0):

`ABMutableMultiValueRef` is a `CFTypeRef`, so perhaps casting the result of `ABRecordCopyValue` to `CFString` instead of `NSString` would be the simple solution.

Comment: This breaks the app. (substituting CFString for NSString*)

Comment: @Cocoa-Dev Sorry, that was my best guess. :-) I have not worked with the Address Book stuff (yet) personally, unfortunately.